# Forward declaration of derived inner class

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors, inner-classes, forward-declaration

I ran into problem implementing some variations of factory method.

```
// from IFoo.h

struct IFoo {

  struct IBar {
    virtual ~IBar() = 0;
    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
  };

  virtual IBar *createBar() = 0;
};

// from Foo.h 
struct Foo : IFoo { // implementation of Foo, Bar in Foo.cpp

  struct Bar : IBar { 
    virtual ~Bar();
    virtual void someMethod();
  };

  virtual Bar *createBar(); // implemented in Foo.cpp
};
```

I'd like to place declaration of Foo::Bar in `Foo.cpp`. For now I cannot succeed:

```
struct Foo : IFoo {

  //struct Bar;        //1. error: invalid covariant return type 
                       //   for ‘virtual Foo::Bar* Foo::createBar()’
  //struct Bar : IBar; //2. error: expected ‘{’ before ‘;’ token

  virtual Bar *createBar(); 
  // virtual IBar *createBar(); // Is not acceptable by-design
};
```

Is there a trick to have just forward declaration of `Boo` in `Foo.hpp` and to have full declaration in `Foo.cpp`?

***EDIT:*** Looks like, I didn't show errors clear. Sо, there are samples in greater detail.

- First trying of forward declaration:

  ```
  struct Foo : IFoo {
    struct Bar;        
    virtual Bar *createBar(); //<- Compile-error
  };
  //error: invalid covariant return type for ‘virtual Foo::Bar* Foo::createBar()’
  ```
- Second trying of forward declaration:

  ```
  struct Foo : IFoo {
    struct Bar : IBar; //<- Compile-error
    virtual Bar *createBar(); 
  };
  // error: expected ‘{’ before ‘;’ token
  ```
- Someone can offer to change return type for `createBar` (from `Bar` to `IBar`)

  ```
  struct Foo : IFoo {
    virtual IBar *createBar(); 
  };
  ```

  However, this workaround is not acceptable by-design

Comment: Thank you. Is it ok after editing?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't forward declare something being a subclass.

Of course, since you're going to hide the class details anyway, you could add another level of indirection.

```
struct IFoo {
  struct IBar {
    virtual ~IBar() = 0;
    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
  };

  virtual IBar *createBar() = 0;
};

// from Foo.h 
struct Foo : IFoo {

    struct Bar : IBar {};

    virtual Bar *createBar();
};    

// In Foo.cpp

struct FooBar : Foo::Bar
{
    virtual ~FooBar() {}
    virtual void someMethod() 
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
};

Foo::Bar* Foo::createBar()
{
    return new FooBar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can do a forward declaration of an embedded class. But then the is-a relation of Bar and IFoo::IBar is only accessible in the implementation file Foo.cpp.

Foo.h:

```
struct Foo : IFoo {

    struct Bar;

    virtual IBar *createBar();
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
struct FooBar::Bar
{
    /* define the nested class here */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to even declare Bar subtype in the Foo class. The Bar can be completely hidden in the source file.

This example demonstrates what I mean :

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct IFoo {

  struct IBar {
    virtual ~IBar(){}
    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
  };

  virtual IBar *createBar() = 0;
};

// from Foo.h 
struct Foo : IFoo { // implementation of Foo, Bar in Foo.cpp


  virtual IBar *createBar(); // implemented in Foo.cpp
};    

namespace {
    struct HiddenBar : IFoo::IBar
    {
        virtual void someMethod(){
            std::cout<<"I am IBar type"<<std::endl;
        }
    };
}

IFoo::IBar* Foo::createBar()
{
    return new HiddenBar;
}


int main() {
    Foo foo;

    auto bar = foo.createBar();

    bar->someMethod();
}
```

Take a note that the HiddenBar should be invisible to the outside world, and accessible only through it's interface. But that means fixing the signature of the `Foo::createBar()` method.

The alternative is to fully declare Foo::Bar in Foo. There are no ways around it.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I cannot change return type of `Foo::createBar()`, because this solution is unacceptable because of design reason (I menioned this case in this quesion).

Comment: @Loom Then you have to fully declare Foo::Bar.